# I'm having errors while trying to run "npx react-native run-android"

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I get an error when I run the following command:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\react-native-cli-test\testeee>npx react-native run-android --no-jetifier
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
:ReactNative:Running 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\react-native-cli-test\testeee\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js config' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\react-native-cli-test\testeee\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 154

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Cannot run program "C:\Users\user\Desktop\react-native-cli-test\testeee\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js": CreateProcess error=193, %1 n�o � um aplicativo Win32 v�lido

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
:ReactNative:Running 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\react-native-cli-test\testeee\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js config' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\react-native-cli-test\testeee\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 154

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Cannot run program "C:\Users\user\Desktop\react-native-cli-test\testeee\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js": CreateProcess error=193, %1 n�o � um aplicativo Win32 v�lido

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\user\Desktop\react-native-cli-test\testeee\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
    at buildAndRun (C:\Users\user\Desktop\react-native-cli-test\testeee\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:179:41)
    at then.result (C:\Users\user\Desktop\react-native-cli-test\testeee\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:133:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: You should tell us what you were trying to do and what you expected to happen.

Comment: As the error suggests did you finished the full setup for android sdk??